# How to get Threshold limit of memory usage in windows 7, 2008

Tags: crash, operating-system, threshold

I need to start logging details of certain heavy applications, the windows event, tasks, services, and hardware information etc once there is a likely possibility for a application crash / hang / windows crash.
In this case I want to get data from windows API's to give me notification or alerts which my application can pick up to understanding that the OS is going to become unstable due to certain parameters.

E.g. 1.The OS could be paralyzed due non availability of physical and virtual memory.
     2.The memory written is contagious and appears to be very much fragmented could lead to some memory handling issues.
     3. Any other memory handling problems.

Does windows support to get such notification or information about condition of unstable application/OS?

Note: The application which I am referring to works on .Net framework 4

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a memory performance counter. Such as one found on TechNet. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx